# Implicit typecasting in C (Converting 32 bit unsigned in to 8 bit u int)

Tags: c, casting

My question looks a lot like

[How to store a 64 bit integer in two 32 bit integers and convert back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810280/how-to-store-a-64-bit-integer-in-2-32-bit-integers-and-convert-back-again)

(I have an unsigned 32 bit I need to put into 4 unsigned 8-bit variables in C)

but

My question is whether this:

```
uint8_t a;
uint32_t b;
a = b;
```

guarantees that a is filled with the eight rightmost bits, rather than the eight leftmost bits?

Answer (score 16):

Yes. Do either this:

```
uint32_t num32 = 0xdeadbeef;

uint8_t a = num32;       /* 0xef */
uint8_t b = num32 >> 8;  /* 0xbe */
uint8_t c = num32 >> 16; /* 0xad */
uint8_t d = num32 >> 24; /* 0xde */
```

Or this:

```
union u
{
    uint32_t num32;

    struct
    {
        uint8_t a;
        uint8_t b;
        uint8_t c;
        uint8_t d;

    } bytes;

} converter;

converter.num32 = 0xdeadbeef;
```

The first example does **not** depend on platform endianess, the second **does**.

Comment: While your first method should work on all compilers and platforms, the second method is limited to platform in little endian format.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the answer, didn't I?

Answer (score 9):

I don’t know what you mean by rightmost and leftmost (endianness?) but C guarantees that `a` will contain the 8 lower-order (least significant) bits of `b`. That is, the assignment will be logically equivalent to:

```
a = b % ((uint32_t)UINT8_MAX + 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

From the C standard, it is guaranteed that `a == b % (max_of_uint8_t + 1)`, i.e. the least significant 8 bits. In §6.3.1.3 (Signed and unsigned integers):

> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, **the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.**

Use `a = b & 0xff` if you need to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the [union declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29). If you can guarantee the processor/source of data won't change I think you can assume '[endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)'