# How to store a 64 bit integer in two 32 bit integers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

As the title says, I'm a little lost on how to accomplish this in Ruby...there are number of topics on how to do this in C or C++. Any ruby experts out there that can chime in on this?

Comment: Are you just trying to store the value, or are you trying to represent the value as two 32-bit integers?  That is, are you trying to take data and then split it in half, or do you want to also have support for adding two 64-bit values each represented with two 32-bit values, etc.?

Comment: the later, the problem is that I have a 64 bit integer value that i need to pass to a service for tracking, they only accept 32 bit integer values, so i need to split the 64 bit value into 2 32 bit values that later i can restich together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same syntax you'd use in C works in ruby, just drop the typecasts:

```
n = 0xFFFFFFFFEEEEEEEE
x = (n & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32
y =  n & 0xFFFFFFFF
puts x.to_s(16)
# => "ffffffff"
puts y.to_s(16)
# => "eeeeeeee"
v = x << 32 | y
puts v.to_s(16)
# => "ffffffffeeeeeeee"
```

If you need the values to be in chunks of exactly 32 bits (i.e. you need to speak binary to some external data file or program), then you'll want to use [Array#pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206) and [String#unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001112) to get the right bits.

Answer (score -1):

one 64bit integer is not equal to two 32bit integers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Comment: how is it done here then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810280/how-to-store-a-64-bit-integer-in-2-32-bit-integers-and-convert-back-again

Comment: i just need to split the 64 bit integer, from what i understand its doable in C, by bit shifting