# Hexadecimal to RGB values in WebGL Shader

Tags: c, html, opengl-es, webgl, fragment-shader

I'm working on an application where I would like to take a single integer input (basically a color) and, using WebGL shaders, color a box with the given input. I planned, originally, to do this with a combination of shifts & a mask as demonstrated below:

```
uniform int u_color;

float rValue = (((u_color) >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0;
float gValue = (((u_color) >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0;
float bValue = ((u_color) & 0xFF) / 255.0;
gl_FragColor = vec4(rValue, gValue, bValue, 1.0);
```

so given the int 0xFF33CC, red=1.0, green=0.2, blue=0.8

However, I ran into a problem and found out that WebGL shaders can't perform bitwise shifts.

I'm wondering how would I be able to efficiently produce the proper FragColor from the given integer, if that's even possible.

**EDIT:** After a bit of trial and error, and thanks to @Jongware, I've come up with a solution

```
uniform int u_color;
float rValue = float(u_color / 256 / 256);
float gValue = float(u_color / 256 - int(rValue * 256.0));
float bValue = float(u_color - int(rValue * 256.0 * 256.0) - int(gValue * 256.0));
gl_FragColor = vec4(rValue / 255.0, gValue / 255.0, bValue / 255.0, 1.0);
```

Other than a clean up, this code is perfect for the job, however I'd always be interested in any other methods different from the one mentioned above.

Comment: Without bit shifting, you can use `/ 256` and `/ 65536`. (But do check if this does not automatically convert your numbers to floats. If they do, you may also need to use mod `%` instead of and `&`.)

Comment: Thanks, I was actually working on that when you suggested that!

Comment: It seems to be the common accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453302/how-do-you-pack-one-32bit-int-into-4-8bit-ints-in-glsl-webgl. As "efficiency" goes, I hope your constants get folded by the fragment compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to your own answer, consider staying with integer math until the end.

```
uniform int u_color;
unsigned rIntValue = (u_color / 256 / 256) % 256;
unsigned gIntValue = (u_color / 256      ) % 256;
unsigned bIntValue = (u_color            ) % 256;
gl_FragColor = vec4(rIntValue / 255.0f, gIntValue / 255.0f, bIntValue / 255.0f, 1.0);
```

Comment: I get error "integer modulus operator supported in GLSL ES 3.0 and above only" regardless of whether I'm using floats or ints.

Comment: @Curtis T'is a C solution as question is tagged  C.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908644/get-accurate-integer-modulo-in-webgl-shader#comment86946387_48909461) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but was in similar situation where I needed to convert the 0-255 `RGB` values into a 0-1 space for the `webGL` color range (which is decimals).

just multiply the color value by `1/255` e.g. an RGB value of RGB(100, 115, 128) can be written as RGB(100 / 255, 115 / 255, 128 / 255)

Since `multiplication is faster than division`, the below is more efficient:

```
RGB(100 * 0.00392156862, 115 * 0.00392156862, 128 * 0.00392156862);
```

Comment: You had a ```u_color``` hexadecimal value not a triple on (R,G,B).