# Get accurate integer modulo in WebGL shader

Tags: webgl, shader, fragment-shader

I want to get an accurate modulo of `x` and `y` in a WebGL fragment shader. `x` and `y` are integers.

Graphing `mod(x,y)`, we get the following:
[image: a choppy, irregular chart]

The actual code used to generate the red-and-black rectangle is:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(mod(
  float(int(v_texCoord[0]*15.))/15.,
  float(int(v_texCoord[1]*15.))/15.
), 0, 0, 1);
```

Where v_texCoord is a vec2 ranging from `0,0` at the top-left to `1,1` at the bottom-right. Precision is set to mediump for both float and int.

Reading the chart, we see that although `mod(6,6)` is correctly `0`, `mod(7,7)` is actually `7`! **How do I fix this?**

I tried to implement my own mod() function. However, it has the same errors, and produces the same graph.

```
int func_mod(int x, int y) {
    return int(float(x)-float(y)*floor(float(x)/float(y)));
}
```

In Javascript, where I can debug it, the function works perfectly. I then tried an iterative approach, because I was worried I was going insane and I didn't trust the floating-point division anyway.

```
int iter_mod(int x, int y) {
    x = int(abs(float(x))); y = int(abs(float(y)));
    for(int i=0; i>-1; i++) {
        if(x < y) break;
        x = x - y;
    }
    return x;
}
```

This worked, but I can't graph it because it crashes linux with an error in ring 0 when I try. It works fine for the spritesheet calculations I need it for, but I really feel it's an incorrect solution.

(Update: It works perfectly on my phone. It's not my code in error now, it's just my problem…)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not modding 7 by 7 you're modding 7/15ths by 7/15ths

Try

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(mod(
  floor(v_texCoord[0] * 15.),
  floor(v_texCoord[1] * 15.)
) / 15., 0, 0, 1);
```

You can see the 2 versions running here

```js
function render(num) {
  var gl = document.getElementById("c" + num).getContext("webgl");
  var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

  var arrays = {
    position: [-1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  };
  var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

  var uniforms = {
    resolution: [gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height],
    intMod: num == 1,
  };

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
}

render(0)
render(1);
```

```css
canvas { margin: 1em; height: 100px; width: 150px; }
div { display: inline-block; }
pre { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
  <script id="vs" type="notjs">
attribute vec4 position;

void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform bool intMod;

void main() {
  vec2 v_texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;

  if (!intMod) {
  
    gl_FragColor = vec4(mod(
      float(int(v_texCoord[0]*15.))/15.,
      float(int(v_texCoord[1]*15.))/15.
    ), 0, 0, 1);

  } else {

    gl_FragColor = vec4(mod(
      floor(v_texCoord[0]*15.),
      floor(v_texCoord[1]*15.)
    )/15., 0, 0, 1);
    
  }
  
}
  </script>
<div><canvas id="c0"></canvas><pre>mod with fractions</pre></div>
<div><canvas id="c1"></canvas><pre>mod with ints</pre></div>
```

You should also note that mod by 0 is undefined meaning you'll get different results on different GPUs

Answer (score 9):

Here is a GLSL function that calculates MOD accurately with (float) parameters that should be integers:

```
/**
 * Returns accurate MOD when arguments are approximate integers.
 */
float modI(float a,float b) {
    float m=a-floor((a+0.5)/b)*b;
    return floor(m+0.5);
}
```

Please note, if a<0 and b>0 then the return value will be >=0, unlike other languages' % operator.

Answer (score 3):

Note that since webGL2, we now have int operations so this problem is now trivially solve by x % y .

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If I try to do `x % y` I get `'%' : integer modulus operator supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only`. From what I understand, the modulus operator is only valid if we specify `#version 130` at the start of our script, but AFAIK no browser supports this version of GLSL ES yet.

Comment: My bad, looks like you can do `#version 300 es` and it works.

Comment: When you see you wrote something wrong, the logic is then to delete the post ;-) .

Comment: I left it in case someone else hits the same issue. If you search the error message online, people say to use `#version 130`, which *doesn't* work in any browsers. I'm hoping my comment can help someone else.