# Is it possible to do a RGBA to float and back round trip and read the pixels in WebGL GLSL ES 1.0?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm asking this question after about a week of trying every possible algorithm, and using probably every prior answer on stackoverflow - with no results. So, please be kind and help a GLSL apprentice.

I am trying to

1. convert RGBA to float
2. perform some calculations
3. convert float to RGBA

inside the GPU - the initial RGBA is defined in javascript via Float32 to Uint8 conversion.

The key thing is being able to do the round trip and read back the floats after doing calculations (GIS distances and similar) in the GPU, for which RGB has too low a resolution.

I want to read the results back into javascript via `gl.readPixels`.

The reasons I start to doubt that it's even possible is:

1. if I do not do a RGBA => float => RGBA conversion everything works ok - the floats I put into the GPU are the floats I get out too - no loss
2. if I do a RGB => float => RGB conversion, it also works fine, all the trouble is with the fourth component either as the least- or most-significant

Please be aware - I suspect this works ok with later versions of GLSL, but this is WebGL GLSL ES 1.0 with a lot more constraints and a lot fewer functionality, and I suspect writing to texture will be a constraint on iOS - which I need.

I have considered listing all the code I tried here - can do if necessary but it seemed like overkill.

Knowing quickly it *is not* possible would be enough for now - I'd stop banging my head against the wall at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, unless I re-write the code I can't post the full answer because I don't have permission to re-license the code as CC-BY-SA-4.0 as required by Stack Overflow

But, there's an MIT licensed GLSL snippet here

https://github.com/mikolalysenko/glsl-read-float/blob/master/index.glsl

Which seems to work for taking a float in a shader and converting an RGBA8 color.

Going the other way you can use any number of ways to get floats in to a shader, uniforms, varyings, even reading from floating point textures is supported by most phones including iPhone AFAIK. Only filtering them (which you don't need) and writing to them is usually not supported.

Here's a test

```js
async function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  gl.canvas.width = 1;
  gl.canvas.height = 1;
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);

  const req = await fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glsl-read-float@1.1.0/index.glsl')
  const glslFn = await req.text();

  const vs = `
  void main() {
    gl_PointSize = 1.0;
    gl_Position = vec4(vec3(0), 1);
  }
  `;

  const fs = `
  precision highp float;
  uniform float value;

  ${glslFn}

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = encode_float(value).abgr;
  }
  `;

  const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
  const vLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, 'value');
  gl.useProgram(prg);

  function test(v) {
    gl.uniform1f(vLoc, v);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
    const f = new Float32Array(1);
    const u = new Uint8Array(f.buffer);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, u);

    console.log(`in: ${(new Float32Array([v]))[0]}, out: ${f[0]}`);
  }

  test(123.456);
  test(0.00913);
  test(1000000.1);
  test(0.0000001);

}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

One thing I'd do is re-write the function so it outputs the values in the opposite order so the swizzle is not needed.

ps: here's a version for Safari because Safari's WebGL support is broken in multiple ways

```js
async function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  gl.canvas.width = 1;
  gl.canvas.height = 1;
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);

  const req = await fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glsl-read-float@1.1.0/index.glsl')
  const glslFn = await req.text();
  
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  void main() {
    gl_PointSize = 1.0;
    gl_Position = position;
  }
  `;

  const fs = `
  precision highp float;
  uniform float value;

  ${glslFn}

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = encode_float(value).abgr;
  }
  `;

  const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
  const vLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, 'value');
  gl.useProgram(prg);
  
  // if safari  
  {
    // Safari fails if you don't have at least one attribute.
    // meaning it fails the WebGL Conformance Tests and has for > 4 years
    // in one of many ways.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 1, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    const pLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "position");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pLoc);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(pLoc, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, 0, 0);
  }

  function test(v) {
    gl.uniform1f(vLoc, v);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
    const f = new Float32Array(1);
    const u = new Uint8Array(f.buffer);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, u);

    console.log(`in: ${(new Float32Array([v]))[0]}, out: ${f[0]}`);
  }

  test(123.456);
  test(0.00913);
  test(1000000.1);
  test(0.0000001);

}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

---

## Update

I guess I can see how you might want to pass your encoded RGBA texture to another shader so that passing in FLOAT textures isn't a solution so I tried to make a RGAB -> Float decoder. This seems to work. No idea if it's entirely correct or what precision issues there are

```js
async function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  gl.canvas.width = 1;
  gl.canvas.height = 1;
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);

  const req = await fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glsl-read-float@1.1.0/index.glsl')
  const glslFn = await req.text();

  const vs = `
    attribute vec4 position;
    void main() {
     gl_PointSize = 1.0;
     // gl_Position = vec4(vec3(0), 1); 
     gl_Position = position; 
  }
  `;

  const fs = `
    precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D tex;

   ${glslFn}
   
   // note: the 0.1s here an there are voodoo related to precision
   float decode_float(vec4 v) {
     vec4 bits = v * 255.0;
     float sign = mix(-1.0, 1.0, step(bits[3], 128.0));
     float expo = floor(mod(bits[3] + 0.1, 128.0)) * 2.0 +
                  floor((bits[2] + 0.1) / 128.0) - 127.0;
     float sig = bits[0] +
                 bits[1] * 256.0 +
                 floor(mod(bits[2] + 0.1, 128.0)) * 256.0 * 256.0;
     return sign * (1.0 + sig / 8388607.0) * pow(2.0, expo);
   }

   void main() {
     float value = decode_float(texture2D(tex, vec2(0)));
     gl_FragColor = encode_float(value).abgr;
   }
`;

  const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
  const vLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, 'value');
  gl.useProgram(prg);

  // if safari  
  {
    // Safari fails if you don't have at least one attribute.
    // meaning it fails the WebGL Conformance Tests and has for > 4 years
    // in one of many ways.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 1, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    const pLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "position");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pLoc);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(pLoc, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, 0, 0);
  }

  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.createTexture());

  function test(v) {
    const float = new Float32Array([v]);
    const data = new Uint8Array(float.buffer);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
    const f = new Float32Array(1);
    const u = new Uint8Array(f.buffer);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, u);

    log(`in: ${(new Float32Array([v]))[0]}, out: ${f[0]}`);
  }

  test(123.456);
  test(0.00913);
  test(1000000.1);
  test(0.0000001);
  test(-123.456);
  test(-0.00913);
  test(-1000000.1);
  test(-0.0000001);
  test(0.0);
  test(1/0);
  test(-1/0);
  test(1.175494351E-38),
  test(3.402823465E37),
  test(1+'foo');  // NaN
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = args.join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}

main();
```

```css
pre { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

note: I didn't deal with any endian issues though ATM there are no common big endian systems I know of.

Comment: Regarding the decode_float(). To make this work I had to reverse the components of "bits". bits[3] should be bits[0], bits[1] should be bits[2], etc. ALSO to make it work accurately on my Moto G Stylus 2020 and my older Nexus 6, (which both use a Qualcomm Adreno GPU), I had to change the 0.1s to 0.2s.