# OpenGL ES write depth data to color

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader, depth-buffer

I'm trying to implement DepthBuffer-like functionality using OpenGL ES on Android.

In other words I'm trying to get the 3D point on surface that is rendered on point [x, y] on the user device. In order to make that I need to be able to read the distance of the fragment at that given point.

**Answer in different circumstances:**

When using normal OpenGL you could achieve this by creating `FrameBuffer` and then attach either `RenderBuffer` or `Texture` with depth component to it.
Both of those approaches use [glReadPixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml), with internal format of `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` to retrieve the data from the buffer/texture. Unfortunately OpenGL ES only supports `GL_ALPHA`, `GL_RGB`, and `GL_RGBA` as the readback formats, so there's really no way to reach the framebuffer's depth data directly.

The only viable approach that I can think of (and that I have found suggested on the internet) is to create different shaders just for depth buffering. The shader, that is used only for depth rendering, should write `gl_FragCoord.z` value (=the distance value that we want to read.) on the `gl_FragColor`. However:

**The actual Question:**

When I write `gl_FragCoord.z` value on the `gl_FragColor = new Vec4(vec3(gl_FragCoord.z), 1.0);` and later use `glReadPixels` to read back the rgb values, those read values don't match up with the input.

**What I have tried:**

I realize that there's only 24 bits (r, g, b * 8 bits each) representing the depth data so I tried shifting the returned value by 8 - to get 32 bits, but it didn't seem to work. I also tried to shift distance when applying it to red, green and blue, but that didn't seem to work as expected. I have been trying to figure out what's wrong by observing the bits, results at the bottom.

fragmentShader.glsl(candidate #3):

```
void main() {

highp float distance = 1.0; //currently just 1.0 to test the results with different values.
lowp float red = distance / exp2(16.0);
lowp float green = distance / exp2(8.0);
lowp float blue = distance / exp2(0.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(red, green, blue, 1.0);

}
```

Method to read the values (=`glReadPixels`)

```
private float getDepth(int x, int y){
    FloatBuffer buffer = GeneralSettings.getFloatBuffer(1); //just creates FloatBuffer with capacity of 1 float value.
    terrainDepthBuffer.bindFrameBuffer(); //bind the framebuffer before read back.
    GLES20.glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer); //read the values from previously bind framebuffer.
    GeneralSettings.checkGlError("glReadPixels"); //Make sure there is no gl related errors.
    terrainDepthBuffer.unbindCurrentFrameBuffer(); //Remember to unbind the buffer after reading/writing.
    System.out.println(buffer.get(0)); //Print the value.
}
```

Observations in bits using the shader & method above:

```
Value   |           Shader input            | ReadPixels output
1.0f    |  111111100000000000000000000000   | 111111110000000100000000
0.0f    |               0                   | 0
0.5f    |   111111000000000000000000000000  | 100000000000000100000000
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453302/how-do-you-pack-one-32bit-int-into-4-8bit-ints-in-glsl-webgl/18454838#18454838

Comment: The last part is wrong because you write to float buffer but the source is unsigned byte: GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE to FloatBuffer. Your shader should work normally without doing any transformation to get the color. You should get a value between 0 and 255. The only thing is you might need to change range of gl_FragCoord.z from [-1,1] to [0,1] so you would need to use "gl_FragCoord.z*0.5 + 0.5". I am not 100% on that one though...

Comment: @MaticOblak `gl_FragCoord.z` is the fragment’s depth mapped in the non-linear range [0,1], which is written to `gl_FragDepth`. See [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) and [What does `gl_FragCoord` contain?](http://www.txutxi.com/?p=182).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you for these. So the question here is why would you even use gl_fragCoord. The z coordinate of position seems to be more interesting to draw as color.