# Packing multiple integers into a 64 bit integer

Tags: c++, c, bit-packing

I want to pack the following numbers into a 64 bit int64_t field in the following order:

- int8_t  num1
- int8_t  num2
- int32_t num3
- int16_t num4

So, the 64 bits should be in the following layout:

```
[  num1(8)  |  num2(8)  |       num3(32)       |   num4(16)  ]
```

I'm not able to wrap my head around the bit packing logic, i.e. I want those numbers to be packed into a single int64_t field, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810280/how-to-store-a-64-bit-integer-in-two-32-bit-integers-and-convert-back-again).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I'm not able to wrap my head around the bit packing logic."* is not a question. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want those numbers to be packed into a single int64_t field similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810280/how-to-store-a-64-bit-integer-in-two-32-bit-integers-and-convert-back-again

Comment: That edit does not make it any better. Have you tried something? What went wrong? Please provide some *specific* problem statement.

Comment: One thing I've seen is to make a union of an int64 and a struct containing the individual fields.  Just be careful about ordering and endianness.

Comment: num = (num1<<56 | (num2<<48) | (num3<<16) | num4)

Comment: @0x5453 That's also UB, at least in C++.

Comment: C or C++? Choose one.

Comment: @arminb And that's UB, too. Are you folks done guessing already? :/

Comment: You keep saying it's UB, but what part is undefined? (genuinely curious)

Comment: @byxor You cannot type-pun through unions and signed integer overflow is UB.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Type-punning through unions seems OK in C, but not C++, which is why the OP needs to choose one language to ask about.

Comment: Do those integers all actually need to be signed? Having to worry about sign extension complicates life ...

Comment: Telling us what you want is not a question nor a problem description. What have you tried so far and where does it fail?

Comment: @0x5453 you forgot to mention padding in your "take care of.." list. ;)

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to ask: do you need to unpack these fields as well, or is it a one-way operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
  int8_t num1;
  int8_t num2;
  int32_t num3;
  int16_t num4;
  ...
  uint64_t number = ((uint64_t)num1 << (16 + 32 + 8)) | ((uint64_t)num2 << (16 + 32)) | ((uint64_t)num3 << 16) | (uint64_t)num4;
```

From this you should be able to figure out how to do the inverse conversion. If not, post another question.