# Glib number conversions

Tags: c, type-conversion, clang, glib

Is there a way how to convert a number to array of lower numbers and back? For example converting guint64 to glong and back.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Possible a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810280/how-to-store-a-64-bit-integer-in-two-32-bit-integers-and-convert-back-again

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. Because memory size of some number types changes with OS.