# Using bitwise operators to add/subtract multiples of 2

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, cpu-architecture

I noticed that the difference between lower and uppercase is `32`.  This seems like a perfect opportunity to utilize some clever bit manipulation.  The problem is that it's been a long time since my Computer Architecture classes, and I'm a bit rusty with the concepts required.  From what I do recall, depending on the CPU architecture and language representation of signed/unsigned there are a very small number of solutions that would apply to almost all programming languages with these operators.  I'm interested in comparing these.  I'm not interested in simply converting the case, I know there are "simpler" ways (for humans, at least).  I'm interested in learning about how this problem interacts with the low-level representation of the data.

Please provide workable, minimal solutions for both lowercase->upper and uppercase->lower, for each common representation, as well as a reasonably detailed explanation of how they work.

Comment: If there's a difference of 32 (which there is), then addition and subtraction are what you need. Nothing fancy. You may be thinking of *shifting* to perform multiplication or division by powers of 2.

Comment: For ASCII assuming C `int c` semantics: `lower2upper(c) = c - 'a' + 'A'` and `upper2lower(c) = c - 'A' + 'a'` and let the compiler do its work. For Unicode text it won't work.

Comment: you probably expect [`c | 0x60`](https://gist.github.com/zed/370497).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, I'd like to see an explanation of how that works in relation to the low-level representation of the data, and how it would change for other common representations.

Comment: Do you want to know how various languages represent bytes as numbers and the corresponding bit-patterns if applicable? For example, [How to combine two 32-bit integers into one 64-bit integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2769598/4279) Do you want to know what assembly/machine code is generated by various compilers/for target architectures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: i'm using `python` here, but this is of course language agnostic. I also do speak about `ascii`, so I'll use a 7-bit representation  of things.)

If you look at the binary representation of `ascii` characters in the `[a-z][A-Z]` range, you'll notice two things:

```
>>> bin(ord('a'))
'0b1100001'
>>> bin(ord('A'))
'0b1000001'
>>> bin(ord('y'))
'0b1111001'
>>> bin(ord('Y'))
'0b1011001'
```

First: they all have the seventh bit (from right) set.
Second: the lowercase characters have the sixth bit (from right) set, the uppercase ones unset, and that's the only difference between a given uppercase character and it's lowercase version (et vice versa).

So all you have to do is flip that bit to toggle case - that would be `xor 0b0100000` which is `xor 0x20`.

To `lower()`, you have to set that bit, so you can `or 0b0100000` which is `or 0x20` - the already mentioned `or 0x60` also works, as 0x60 is 0b1100000 and that bit is set anyway.

And to upper, you have to unset that bit, that would be "and the inverse of the mask 0b0100000", which is the same as `and 0x5f`.

To see it all in action, i wrote some python snipplets which check that what we just saw is true for every character in the english alphabet:

```
#toggle():
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(c)^0x20) for c in string.ascii_lowercase) == string.ascii_uppercase
True
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(c)^0x20) for c in string.ascii_uppercase) == string.ascii_lowercase
True

#lower():
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(c)|0x20) for c in string.ascii_lowercase) == string.ascii_lowercase
True
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(c)|0x20) for c in string.ascii_uppercase) == string.ascii_lowercase

#upper():
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(c)&0x5f) for c in string.ascii_lowercase) == string.ascii_uppercase
True
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(c)&0x5f) for c in string.ascii_uppercase) == string.ascii_uppercase
True
```

**it does not do anything useful to `' '`, `'\n'`, and such though!**